# Notify apps to clear cache after login or logout from Keycloak

Tags: tomcat, addeventlistener, keycloak, openid-connect

I am trying to set up Keycloak and my app is on Tomcat. I have the adapter Keycloak for Tomcat. I want my app to set up the session and clear the cache each time a user login or logout.

So I want to be able to know on my apps side when Keycloak log me in or log me out. I want to catch these events after they have been successful.
I have heard about SPI EventListener but there is notification of only some Login and some Logout (for example, logout all is not a Logout event -> it doesnt appears in Keycloak admin console and with my app I need to be able to detect it). Is there a better solution ?

I have seen also in Keycloak adapter code that there is a K_LOGOUT notification for every logout. Is there the same for LOGIN ?

Is it better to create a filter in Tomcat to catch these notifications ?

Thanks for your help.